# How is "thaw" different from "resume"?

Tags: power-management

In power management, what is  "thaw"?

How is it different from  "resume"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thaw must be "resume" from hibernation. Literally it is resume from disk.

Comment: what is "resume"?

Comment: It is "wake up" from "sleep" mode.